# How do I drag an item behind my vehicle in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I saw this in some player's YouTube video. They can drag a shell so that they don't get hit by other people's red shells. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like when using the Wheel, it is by holding left or right on D-pad.

Answer (score 7):

You just hold down whichever button is normally pressed for shooting the item.

As soon as you release the button the item will then fire, and as far as I know you cannot stop holding the item behind you without firing.

This works with single shells, single bananas and possibly the fake power-up boxes.

Comment: It does indeed work with the fake power-up box. I think it also works with the leader bomb (blue shell). That was especially good in Mario Kart 64, because if you managed to get into the lead and carried a leader bomb behind you, it was effectively a permanent shield to red shells coming from behind.

Comment: I tried it with shell and it didn't work...  are you sure?

Comment: @動靜能量 I'm fairly sure, it's a tactic I use regularly when playing Mario Kart games. Which item was it, and what button are you holding?

Comment: Yes, just hold whichever item button you use: http://bit.ly/9RLN32

Comment: If you use the Wii Wheel, you need to hold left on D-pad (when held landscape).

Comment: Note that the ¿ Block item doesn't actually shield you from incoming shells. The shells and bananas work though.

Comment: note that you can control which way the shells etc. fire by holding up and down respectively on the d-pad.

Comment: @Mag: I'm pretty sure that if a shell hits the ¿ box when it's on the track, that stops it. So if you hear a shell coming up behind you should be able to drop the box just before the shell hits.

Answer (score -2):

Tap Down once on the D-pad to hold it behind you. To shoot behind you, tap Down again. With triple shells, you effectively have a wall of death around you.

Comment: Tapping will only cause the item to be shot or dropped behind you. (Unless it's a triple item, of course. But most aren't.)